# UIWebView contentInset without extra height at bottom

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, uiscrollview

I'm creating a view controller that uses a web view which slides behind the navigation bar and status bar. To do this, I'm setting the `webView.scrollView.contentInset` property to have a top inset of `64`.

However, this doesn't shrink the amount of area the web view wants to take up, so if a page is less than a screenful, it has 64 px of white space at the bottom to scroll through. The web views are in a vertical `UIPageViewController`, so this disrupts paging. Is there some way to get rid of this extra space?

Comment: Do you want the web view content to go behind the navigation bar and status bar? or the navigation bar scroll with the web view behind the status bar?

Comment: When you scroll the web view, I want it to slide behind the translucent navigation bar and status bar. (I'm actually doing this on iOS 7, so it's one of the fancy new blurry navigation bars, but the way UIWebView scrolling is done doesn't seem to have changed.) I've implemented the scroll-with behavior before, but it's not what I'm looking for in this app.

Comment: oh. I think i know what you want, its not contentInset because that moves the content of the web view. If you want the web view to show behind the navigation bar and stuff, you set clipsToBounds to NO

Comment: Could you boil that down to a simple example project that shows the problem? That would make fixing it much easier.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've sort of made an end-run around this problem by disabling scrolling on short pages. Basically, I use `-stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` to run some JavaScript inside the page that walks down from `document.body` and computes the position of the bottom of the bottommost element. (`document.body` itself is always at least as large as the viewport, so I can't look at its size.) Then, back in Objective-C-land, I compare that to the height of the web view (less the inset), and if it's less, I disable scrolling. This is not a perfect solution, but it covers the worst symptoms.

If someone can come up with a better solution than this, I'd love to hear about it! Either way, I can't award the bounty to myself, so someone will be getting it.

Comment: In all honesty, I don't think this should be marked as the correct answer, considering there are better options like the one provided by Chris Truman . Messing with JavaScript to check the position of the bottommost element is bad.

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried something like adjusting the webview's scrollview content insets? Example:

```
    webView.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0,64, 0)
```

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like what you need is to adjust the `webView.scrollView.contentSize` and adjust the height by 64.  You may need to provide more information about how it slides behind the nav bar and status bar to help me answer this.  I would take a look at this section of the Scroll View Programming Guide:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/CreatingBasicScrollViews/CreatingBasicScrollViews.html

Comment: See my comment on the question for a little more detail about what I'm doing. I assume that the `contentSize` should only change if the page is less than a full screen tall, right? How would I determine that?

Comment: Well when your WebView loads, the contentSize will probably tell you how high the content is. It sounds more like you need to set the contentInset.bottom = 64, as well.

Answer (score 1):

Change the clipsToBounds.

```
webView.clipsToBounds = NO;
```

This will make its content visible outside its frame, so set its frame like normal, right under the navigation bar. The navigation bar will be translucent and you will see its content under it.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work in this case because they're in a UIPageViewController. The web view in one controller overflows its edges and ends up overlapping the controllers above and below it, apparently interfering with the page controller's gesture recognizers.

Comment: It shouldn't, it doesnt allow touches in those places you can now see it, justs shows it. and Ive never tried page controller so i dont know, i thought that would work.

Comment: Another way might be to set your view controller to want full screen layout... then go from there. `UIViewController` sets `clipsToBounds=YES` on one or more of the views it manages... I can't remember if setting `viewController.wantsFullScreenLayout=YES` resolves that or not.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to disable Autolayout for the web view!